# How to reply when someone says 'you deserve this'

Tags: word-choice, expressions, politeness

I always wonder if it is okay to reply with just a '**Thanks**' when someone says '*you deserve this*' or '*you have done a great job*'. Can someone please advise me about whether saying 'Thanks' and leaving it at that is okay, or whether I should add something more to my response?

Answer (score 1):

I use "very kind of you to say so". That accepts the compliment and turns it round so as to compliment the speaker. Warm glows of appreciation all round!

Answer (score 0):

A simple '**Thanks**' seems appropriate, but also on the edge of curtness. You could instead reply with '**duly appreciated**' or a more specific thank you like:

> Thanks for your support, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I will take this as an opportunity where I get to say : 
"We ^all^ deserve to grow; only happy to make our community more empowered and actuated."